# Is injectivity of $2^{(\ldots)}$ weaker than $\mathsf{GCH}$?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, gch

The following statement [cannot](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=182924) be proven in $\mathsf{ZFC}$:

> > (S) : If $A, B$ are sets with $|A| < |B|$, then $2^{|A|} = |{\cal P}(A)| < |{\cal P}(B)| = 2^{|B|}$.

Obviously, $\mathsf{GCH}$ implies (S). Does (S) imply $\mathsf{GCH}$ too?

Comment: You may find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742448/regarding-the-axiom-2-kappa-2-kappa-for-regular-cardinals-kappa-an) relevant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, take Merimovich's model in which  $2^\kappa=\kappa^{+3}$ for all cardinals $\kappa.$

Merimovich, Carmi [A power function with a fixed finite gap everywhere](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=9156282&fileId=S0022481200005272). J. Symbolic Logic 72 (2007), no. 2, 361–417.

Let me add that the statement "the power function is injective" is known as weak GCH, which has important applications. See [Why the weak GCH is true!](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jbaldwin/asl07.pdf) .

Answer (score 11):

One can answer this easily with [Easton's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem), which shows that we can have $2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_{n+2}$ for all finite $n$, and $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$ for all other infinite cardinals $\kappa$. In this model, the continuum function is still one-to-one, but the GCH fails. So the answer is no.